# Javascript Error Wordpress Admin : Uncaught TypeError: a.widget is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wp-admin

I installed a fresh Wordpress 4.9.8 on your System using the commandline tool: WP-CLI.

Everything seams to work fine in the frontend. But in the backend I get the following error on the Dashboard:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.widget is not a function
```

When using the Customizer I get even more Errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

In addition to this I don't see the Icons on the Admin Dashboard. But when I want to create or edit a Post everything is fine.

I know that this looks like a typical: U got your jQuery not added right thing. But it's a fresh clearn Wordpress 4.9.8 without any customisation. How can there be those errors?

Hopefully somebody can help me with this, cause I don't want to start messing with it unless it works properly.

Comment: is it in local or someother server

Comment: It is not local. Its hosted on a Server and accessed through a normal URL

Comment: then your jquery is hacked. Please check whether jQuery.js file exists inside the wp-admin folder

Comment: in the wp-admin/js folder are no jquery files. So I checked the Github of Wordpress to see if there should be a jquery file. And in the github there is although no jquery file.

So it seams okay to me

Comment: The jQuery files I found are all under wp-includes/js/jquery

And they seam complete compared to GitHub